# PJ065A(CUI) based clarification

Tags: pcb, design, connector

I need some clarification on the [PJ065A DC power jack](http://www.cui.com/product/resource/pj-065x.pdf). It has 3 contacts how do I connect the PJ065A with an LM2675 IC? Which one of the pins (PJ065A) goes to the VIN pin of the LM2675 IC?

Comment: which is the Center Positive pin of PJ065A

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you do is to take your power supply jack plug and put it into the **unconnected socket** (PJ065A). Then use a multimeter (set to volts) to determine which pins on the socket are the 0V and which the +V. Then its a simple matter of wiring from there.

Comment: because we need to send a circuit for PCB designing?

Comment: @user26039 have updated answer